# Synchronizing between multiple pexpect processes

Tags: pexpect

I am writing an application that requires to ssh and telnet to a device at the same time.
The pseudo code goes something like this.

```
p1 = pexpect.spawn("ssh to the device")
p1.send("run some command")
p1.expect("..")

p2 = pexpect.spawn("telnet to same device")
p2.send("run a command that can be run only through telnet")
p2.expect("..")

p1.send("run some other command")
p1.expect("..")

p2.send("run another command that can be run only through telnet")
p2.expect("..")`
```

If you notice, I need synchronization between two pexpect children
in order to run them one after the other.
I searched a lot but could not find any information.
please help.
thanks

Comment: I think the reason this question has no answers is because it is not clear what the problem is. The pseudocode you wrote seems fine and the synchronization should work because you wait for p1 to finish its command (p1.expect) before running anything through p2, and visa versa. Perhaps you are trying to learn what kind of thing to wait on (that is, what to put instead of "..")? I would normally look for the prompt. Hope that helps.